# How to resolve update lock issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have 2 MySQL UPDATE Query problem on my website.

**Problem 1**

I run a content site that updates page views for posts when users read.

Each time I send push notifications, my server times out; when I comment on the Update query that increments the page views, everything returns to normal.

This I think maybe as a result of hundreds of UPDATE query trying to update the views on the same row.

```
**The query that updated the tablename**    

update table set views='$newview' where id=1


Query Explain

id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: new_jobs
type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 4
ref: NULL
rows: 1
Extra: Using where


**tablename create table**

CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `job_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `advert_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `expiry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `no_deadline` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
 `source` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `featured` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
 `views` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
 `email_status` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
 `draft` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
 `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `show_company_name` int(1) DEFAULT 1,
 `display_application_method` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
 `status` int(1) DEFAULT 1,
 `upload_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `country` int(1) DEFAULT 1,
 `followers_email_status` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
 `og_img` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `old_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `new_jobs_company_id_index` (`company_id`),
 KEY `new_jobs_views_index` (`views`),
 KEY `new_jobs_draft_index` (`draft`),
 KEY `new_jobs_country_index` (`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=151359 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What is the best way of handling this?

[Scenario 2 removed on request]

Comment: This is really two different questions. Maybe split scenario 2 to a separate question. Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`. Explain more detail what server crashes entails. "to update the views" - what views? Needs more explanation with maybe more examples.

Comment: Use **prepared statements** for query see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @danblack Question is improved.

Comment: Have you checked `EXPLAIN` results for both queries? Additionally, keep in mind that the query from the second scenario is widely open for SQL injection

Comment: @NicoHaase I have added the EXPLAIN

Comment: Is "times out" the web browser giving up, php killing of the page, or MySQL giving an error. If so what is the exact error in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 1. I would expect the update of a 'view' count (or 'click' or 'like' or whatever) to be more like

```
UPDATE t SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = 123;
```

I assume you have an index (probably the `PRIMARY KEY`) on `id`?

Since there are other things going on with that table, it may be wise to split off the rapidly incrementing counter into a separate table.  This would avoid interfering with other queries.  You can get other data, plus the counter, by using `JOIN .. USING(id)`.

Scenario 2 does not make sense.  It seems to keep the latest date for each email, but what does `country` mean?  Since it seems like more than just a counter, you might want a separate table to log those 3 columns.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

There are many things that novices perceive as a "crash".  Please describe further -- out of connections, out of disk space, sluggishness, the client gave error message, other operations taking too long, etc.  Each has a different remedy.

**Query**

Are you are currently logically doing

```
BEGIN;
$ct = SELECT views ... FOR UPDATE;
...
UPDATE ... SET views = $ct+1 WHERE ...;
COMMIT;
```

If so, that is much less efficient than

```
(with autocommit = ON)
UPDATE ... SET views = views+1 ...;
```

Note that the first version hangs onto the row longer.  If you fail to use `FOR UPDATE`, you will drop some counts.

Splitting into a separate table sort of forces you to run the `UPDATE` as its own transaction.

**Other**

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`:

- Default is 1, which is secure, but leads to at least one IOPs for each transaction.
- 2 leads to a flush once a second.  During intense times, this is much more efficient.  But a crash could lose up to one second's worth of updates.  the inaccuracy of "view count" due to a rare crash is, in my opinion, acceptable.

`KEY(views)` needs to be updated every time `views` is changed.  But, thanks to the "change buffer", this is unlikely to involve any extra I/O, at least now while you are doing the `UPDATE`.

`INT(1)` takes 4 bytes; the `(1)` has no meaning.  Suggest changing to `TINYINT` (1 byte), thereby saving about 27 bytes per row.  (7 columns plus 2 indexes)

`country INT(1)` -- Is it a flag?  What is the meaning?  Is it normalized to another table?  Using 4 bytes for an id and an extra table when standard abbreviations ('US', 'UK', 'RU', 'IN', etc) would take 2 bytes?  Suggest `country CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci`.

Indexing flags rarely benefits.  Let's see the queries where you think such indexes might be used.  And the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for them.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. I have improved the question. Kindly check.

Comment: If I move the views to a separate table, will it solve the problem of updating a row frequently in a short time? Will the lock waits on the new table affect the server?

Comment: A separate table keep the table size smaller so its more likely to still be in the innodb buffer (btw what's your `show global status like 'innodb_buffer%'; SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime'`. `views=views+1` also keeps the count accurate rather than a race condition if you're retrieving the value to update and calculating that in php.

Comment: @danblack - Thanks.  You brought up an important issue or two.

Comment: @OguguaBelonwu - I added a lot to my Answer.